# How to find the marginal probability function concerning sex of children in household?

Tags: probability

[image]

Unsure of how to arrive at the probability function given below for part (b).

$$P(Y=y)=\sum_{x=y}^{8}\left(\begin{array}{l}{x} \\ {y}\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x} f(x)$$

We should somehow be able to derive it from the $f(x)$ probability function, but the logic is escaping me. Here's how far I've gotten:

- choose $y$ girls from $x$ children: $x \choose y$
- Each child has half probability of being female.. $\frac{1}{2}$

And that's about it. I'm not sure why we are summing up things or why we are raising $\frac{1}{2}$ to the power of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that$$P(Y=y)=P(Y=y\wedge\text{family has $y$ children})+P(Y=y\wedge\text{family has $y+1$ children})+...+P(Y=y\wedge\text{family has $8$ children})\\=\sum_{x=y}^8 P(Y=y\mid\text{family has $x$ children})P(\text{family has $x$ children})\\=\sum_{x=y}^8 P(Y=y\mid\text{family has $x$ children})f(x)$$since the maximum number of children in a family is $8$. For a family with $x$ children, the number of girls is a binomial variate with probability of success $p=1/2$. So the probability that there are $y$ girls (and $x-y$ boys) out of $x$ children is$$P(Y=y\mid\text{family has $x$ children})=\binom xy\left(\frac12\right)^y\left(\frac12\right)^{x-y}$$and the PMF of $Y$ becomes$$f_Y(y)=\sum_{x=y}^8\binom xy\left(\frac12\right)^xf(x)$$

Comment: How do you know $P(Y=y | \text { family has } x \text { children })$ and $P(\text { family has } x \text { children })$ events are independent? Since you are assuming their intersection is equivalent to their products.

Comment: @herophant No, I did not assume they are independent. I simply used the conditional probability relation:$$P(Y=y|X=x)=\frac{P(Y=y\wedge X=x)}{P(X=x)}$$where $X=x$ is the event that the family has $x$ children.